# Issue with visualising data scraped with edgar library in python

Tags: python, edgar

I am currently trying to use the edgar library in Python to download S1 filings from the SEC EDGAR database. I tried running the example code that is given in the library project description, which is as follows:

```
company = edgar.Company("Oracle Corp", "0001341439")
tree = company.get_all_filings(filing_type = "10-K")
docs = company.get_documents(tree, no_of_documents=1)
```

The code seems to work, but I cannot understand how to retrieve the document after it has been saved as a variable.
Typing docs returns <Element sec-document at 0x7f8bbd0de720>.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you had any luck? You can get the document's content as a string by doing `docs[0].text_content()`